# Register a service worker in the webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, service-worker

I use webpack to build my React app. I can not understand how to point the way to my service worker. In the `index.js` file, I successfully receive a registration message, but I cannot access the file of the service worker in `public/serviceWorker.js`

WebPack config

```
 plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        favicon: 'public/favicon.ico'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
        swDest: path.join(__dirname, 'build/serviceWorker.js'),
        clientsClaim: true,
        skipWaiting: true
    })
],
```

index.js

```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                    userVisibleOnly: true,
                    applicationServerKey: convertedVapidKey
                })
                    .then((subscription) => {
                        sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: review the value of your "swDest" property to change the SW output folder

Comment: Please explain more. I do not understand what it means